# How to stop knitr from adding tex packages based on documentClass?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave

For example, I have a simple minimal .Rnw file, which is the following :

```
<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
test = "test"
@
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Test value is \Sexpr{test}

\end{document}
```

All I want it knit to replace the Sexpr variables, but it is adding a whole bunch of preamble based on the documentclass.

I'm working on a limited docker environment so I don't have those packages in tex.

How can I make knitr not add all that pre code?

This is output from knitr:

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage[]{graphicx}\usepackage[]{color}
% maxwidth is the original width if it is less than linewidth
% otherwise use linewidth (to make sure the graphics do not exceed the margin)
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{ %
  \ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth
    \linewidth
  \else
    \Gin@nat@width
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\definecolor{fgcolor}{rgb}{0.345, 0.345, 0.345}
\newcommand{\hlnum}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.686,0.059,0.569}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlstr}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.192,0.494,0.8}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlcom}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.678,0.584,0.686}{\textit{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\hlopt}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlstd}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.345,0.345,0.345}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwa}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.161,0.373,0.58}{\textbf{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwb}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.69,0.353,0.396}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwc}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.333,0.667,0.333}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwd}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.737,0.353,0.396}{\textbf{#1}}}%
\let\hlipl\hlkwb

\usepackage{framed}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{kframe}{%
 \def\at@end@of@kframe{}%
 \ifinner\ifhmode%
  \def\at@end@of@kframe{\end{minipage}}%
  \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}%
 \fi\fi%
 \def\FrameCommand##1{\hskip\@totalleftmargin \hskip-\fboxsep
 \colorbox{shadecolor}{##1}\hskip-\fboxsep
     % There is no \\@totalrightmargin, so:
     \hskip-\linewidth \hskip-\@totalleftmargin \hskip\columnwidth}%
 \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width
   \@totalleftmargin\z@ \linewidth\hsize
   \@setminipage}}%
 {\par\unskip\endMakeFramed%
 \at@end@of@kframe}
\makeatother

\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.97, .97, .97}
\definecolor{messagecolor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{warningcolor}{rgb}{1, 0, 1}
\definecolor{errorcolor}{rgb}{1, 0, 0}
\newenvironment{knitrout}{}{} % an empty environment to be redefined in TeX

\usepackage{alltt}
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Test value is test

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was about to answer with `opts_knit$set(header = "")`, but interestingly this does not remove all the fluff from the preamble. BTW, please consider making your code minimal and reproducible by replacing the JSON stuff with regular variables.

Comment: Thanks for testing, I edited the code to be more reproducible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really stop this without modifying the `knitr` code.  Some extra packages are hard coded into the `knitr:::make_header_latex` function, which you can see in https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/dccdad769b67a23d9cf8b8414f844e2a6a74f21e/R/header.R#L16 .

However, there are ways to modify that function on the fly, using the fairly dangerous `assignInNamespace` function:

```
assignInNamespace("make_header_latex", function(...) "", "knitr")
```

After this,

```
knit("minimal.Rnw")
```

produces this output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\begin{document}

Test value is test

\end{document}
```

(The `upquote` line comes from a different function, but it should be safe because of `\IfFileExists`.)

Be careful if you do this, because the change I made will last for the rest of your R session.

**Edited to add:**  If you want, you can put that `assignInNamespace` line into
a code chunk in the document.  If you're using RStudio and knit the document by clicking on "Compile PDF", it will start a new R session, do the knitting (which will replace the function), and then run the patched-in function:  so you get the effect you want without messing up `knitr` in your current session.